# Using C# Reflection to assign collection of variable size to class properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a destination class called `Foo` with the following properties:

```
public string Bar1 { get; set; }
public string Bar2 { get; set; }
public string Bar3 { get; set; }
public string Bar4 { get; set; }
public string Bar5 { get; set; }
public string Bar6 { get; set; }
```

I'm reading in a file that could have any number of "Bars" which I read into a collection called `fileBars`. I need to find out how to use Reflection to iterate over `fileBars` and assign the first one to `Bar1`, the second one to `Bar2`, etc.

I've tried several things I've found online, most recently playing with what's shown below, but I haven't had any luck. Can someone who is familiar with Reflection point me in the right direction?

```
var count = fileBars.Count();
var myType = Foo.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] barProperties = null;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    barProperties[i] = myType.GetProperty("Bar" + i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a single `string[]` or `ICollection<string>` property?

Comment: Note that your building of the property name is incorrect. As you have it now you'll build "Bar01", "Bar11", "Bar21". You need to have `"Bar" + (i + 1)`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to store the `PropertyInfo` objects in an array; you can just assign the values as you go:

```
var count = fileBars.Count();
var instance = new Foo();

for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    var property = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar" + i);
    if(property != null)
       property.SetValue(instance, fileBars[i - 1];
    else 
       // handle having too many bars to fit in Foo

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `barProperties`:

```
PropertyInfo[] barProperties = new PropertyInfo[count];
```

To assign a value to the property, use `SetValue`:

```
barProperties[i].SetValue(Foo, fileBars[i] );
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says the class name Foo is not valid at this point in the SetValue line.

Comment: He meant `typeof(Foo)`

Comment: Since you use `Foo.GetType()` in your question I assumed `Foo` was an instance.  If `Foo` is a type then use `typeof(Foo)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to keep all the properties you find for later, you don't need the `barProperties` array:

```
var myType = foo.GetType();
int barCount = 0;
foreach(string barValue in fileBars)
{
    barCount++;
    var barProperty = myType.GetProperty("Bar" + barCount);
    barProperty.SetValue(foo, barValue, null);
}
```